# how to access object properties in json using beautifulsoup? python

Tags: python, arrays, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
import requests
ua = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
import soupsieve as sv


url = "https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8,%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80&results=500&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=d9168899-cf24-452a-95cf-06d7ac5a982b"
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": ua.random})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find("p"))
```

i want to choose from this list only two properties like "boundedBy" and "coordinates"
How can i do it?I ve checked the whole bs documentation, but didnt find a solution

Comment: why would you use beautifulsoup to parse json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from the server is in Json format, so use json parser or `.json()` method to decode it:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8,%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80&results=500&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=d9168899-cf24-452a-95cf-06d7ac5a982b"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["properties"]["ResponseMetaData"]["SearchRequest"]["boundedBy"])
```

Prints:

```
[[37.048427, 55.43644866], [38.175903, 56.04690174]]
```

Comment: And one more question. I need only "boundedBy" properties of all elements, how can i do it?

Comment: @odosd Try `for f in data['features']:  print(f['properties']['boundedBy'])`  - essentially, `data` is normal python dictionary that contains lists/dictionaries so you work with it as other dictionary in Python.

Comment: thanks a lot one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.json()` method of the response, since the data is JSON.  You can then iterate over the features in the response.  Note you can set the parameters separate from the URL so they are readable and easier to change:

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1'

params = {'text': 'Почта России, Краснодар',
          'results': 500,
          'type': 'biz',
          'lang': 'ru_RU',
          'apikey': 'd9168899-cf24-452a-95cf-06d7ac5a982b'}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
if r.ok:
    data = r.json()
    for feature in data['features']:
        x,y = feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]
        (x1,y1),(x2,y2) = feature["properties"]["boundedBy"]
        print(f'coordinates ({x:.6f}, {y:.6f}): bounds ({x1:.6f}, {y1:.6f})-({x2:.6f}, {y2:.6f})')
```

Output:

```
coordinates (38.969711, 45.028356): bounds (38.965656, 45.025508)-(38.973867, 45.031330)
coordinates (38.969660, 45.028365): bounds (38.965656, 45.025508)-(38.973867, 45.031330)
coordinates (38.993199, 45.063675): bounds (38.989012, 45.060879)-(38.997223, 45.066698)
coordinates (39.029821, 45.048676): bounds (39.025753, 45.045304)-(39.033964, 45.051124)
coordinates (38.992736, 45.034352): bounds (38.988590, 45.031496)-(38.996801, 45.037318)
...
```